# Why I get Incorrect syntax near '=' error

Tags: c#, sqldatadapter

I tried bind a label from datatable

I get this error

```
  Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

at this line

```
 da.Fill(dt);
```

My code : Page_Load

```
LbLID.Text =this.Page.Request.QueryString["DI"].ToString();

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB;User 
 ID=sa;Password="pass);
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table1 where ID= " + 
 LbLID.Text.Trim(), con);

 System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);
 lblS1.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
 lblS1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What's the value of `LbLID.Text.Trim()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't break normal string literals across multiple lines, also your closing quote is misplaced:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=pass");
```

Or use a verbatim literal, which you *can* break across multiple lines:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    @"Data Source=local;
      Initial Catalog=DB;
      User ID=sa;
      Password=pass");
```

That said, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. For your own sake, and the sake of your users, you really should use parameterized queries instead of concatenating your SQL queries like that.

Here's a quick example:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Table1 where ID = @ID", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", LbLID.Text.Trim());
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    lblS1.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
    lblS1.DataBind();
}
```

Some other tips: You should avoid using `select *` queries, since your database schema might change, and that would break any existing code. It would be better to select only the column you're interested in and make a simple call to [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I just assumed that was the OP formatting it for SO.. the error isn't a compiler error, it's a SQL error.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I suppose that's possible, too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table1 where ID ='" + 
                        LbLID.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
```

However note that it a very bad code which is vulnerable to sql injection.

So you should try this:

```
var com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=@id", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("id",LBLID.Text.Trim());
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
```

Or shorter:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=@id", con);
da.SelectCommand.AddWithValue("id",LBLID.Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a SQL error. You aren't passing in a valid ID.

It's one of two things.

Option A: Your ID is a string. In which case.. you need to use single quotes:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Table1 where ID= '" + LbLID.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
```

Option B: Your LbLId is wrong.. you're checking for `["DI"]` .. when I think it should be `["ID"]`:

```
LbLID.Text =this.Page.Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
```

Comment: localhost:1611/Dealer.aspx?DI=428116920

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem in the code at da.Fill(). But I see another issue at the following statement:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB;User 
 ID=sa;Password="pass);
```

`...Password="pass);` - rather is should be

```
...Password=" + pass);
```

OR

```
...Password=pass");
```

I am wondering you are not getting an undefined variable error for pass*.

Comment: No.I did not see Password="pass)  when write question to here.Solved by @p.s.w.g answer